# Aws Route 53 Public Hosted Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

Can Aws public hosted zone work without a registered domain?

I created a hosted zone for the domain name e.g example.com. keep in mind I don’t own nor register the domain name, I just used it for the hosted zone. Then I created the record to route traffic to my elasticbeanstalk application. It didn’t work.

Did it not work because I didn’t own the domain?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your question ?

Comment: You have to own the domain. Otherwise, what would stop to create HZ `amazon.com` and use that for your app?